# how to share html content on whatsapp?

Tags: android, html, whatsapp

```
String Content = Constants.SHARING_PROGRAM_DETAIL +
                        "< b r > <b r> <b>" + prog Name + "</b>
</b r></b r>" + "  " +
                        "<b r>" + "   " + "</b r>" +
                        "<b r>" + synopsis + "</b r>" + "   " +
                        "<b r>" + "   " + "</b r>" +
                        "b" + " Also Showing On:  " +
                        "<br>" + "   " + "</br>" +
                        "</br>" + StartDateTime;

//                //pop up all options of share
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.setType("*/*");


 i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, progName);

i.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(shareContent));
                start Activity(Intent.create Chooser(i, "Share via"));
```

i have used  this code .. can anyone tell me the mistake here
my content is not getting shared with whatsapp

Comment: I'm not Android developer, but I believe that WhatsApp only accept *bold*, _italic_ and ~strikethrough~. Line breaks you should try with "\n" or "\r\n". Another approach is to use url encode: try something like %0 for line breaking and %20 for space. Good luck.

Comment: this code will work on other intent also like gmail or messages ?

Comment: I really don't know. You should test it. It's the best way to discover.